How do you say putting multiple supermarket bags in such a way to end up with a single bag to easily manage
When you leave a supermarket, sometimes you have 3-4 bags each with various fullness. Some have just one eggplant, or a parsley, some have even smaller fruits to get weighed seperately. In such a case, we put a bag into a more spacious one, and then that one to even more spacious one until you end up with a single bag to avoid carrying many small bags around. Today, I wondered how to say this to myself, but couldn't be sure if what I come up are correct at all:
Let's imagine there were 3 or 4 bags. What do you say:
1- So, let's put them into one another
2- So, let's put them inside one another.
3- So, let's put one into the other.
4- So, let's put one inside the other.
5- So, let's put each one inside the other.
Of all, number 5 sounds better to me, however it has a logical mistake, because you can't put the last bag into another bag.
I am confused how to make a sentence that says it naturally without a logical mistake.

Do you mean: with or without groceries in them? Your question is not clear. If you have a bag of groceries, in the US, it's common to use: double bag the groceries. to avoid the bag splitting. Otherwise, for empty bags, which happens after you get home, you fold them up and put them in a bag that is not folded. None of this increases the size of the bags...Usually, three folded bags will fit into the  unfolded one.

@Lambie, with groceries in them, but some of them have only a few small items. The reason to combine them into one bag is not to prevent bag splitting but because itis easier to handle one bag when carrying.

Yunus, we (in the US) do not usually leave a grocery store or supermarket with a half-full bag and three empty ones. The half-full bag is just that. Two others would be folded and put into the third one, at home. After full bags are emptied.

In the UK at least, shops nowadays give out as few bags as possible to minimise plastic waste. You wouldn't leave a supermarket with several partly-filled bags. If I was on a shopping expedition and had bags from different shops with only a few items in, I could say "I put the smaller bags into the big one" or "I incorporated all my shopping into one bag".

My understanding, based you your comment, is that you combined the contents of the bags, you didn't combine the bags themselves.  Is that correct?

@JamesK, No not just the contents, but the bags, too. To clarify: One small bag had just a parsley, the other bag had a few eggplants and a few zucchinis, and the last bag (the biggest one) had a few more other things. So, we put the smallest bag with the parsley into the bag with the eggplants and zucchinis, so the two bags now seem like a one bigger bag, and then we put that bigger bag into the biggest bag, so we ended up one big bag.

Simple solution is to not worry about the logic error. If you're looking for something that's absolutely unambiguous and cannot me misconstrued, it's going to seriously restrict any possible answer.

Generally, supermarket bags are the same size.  Your ended up with "one big bag" makes no sense. Ended up with one full bag. That said, do you have various sizes of bag where you live? In any case, a smaller paper bag can also  be put into a larger one.

@Lambie The supermarkets (Lulu mall) have bags of 4-5 sizes and we too combine the bags to make it easier to carry.. It is not an impossible thing.

@JamesMathai In any event, you can also place a smaller container into a larger one. But in the states, we generally only have one size of bag or two at the most.

Lets put all the items /everything in one bag It doesn't matter if the veg are in small individual plastic bags that supermarkets supply customers with when they weigh  fresh produce on a scale. No one is going to carry a small bag of parsley, and a bag of celery separately.

You're overthinking and trying to be absolutely unambiguous when it's really not justified by the context.

Let's put everything in one bag.

Whether you put the aubergine in the bag, or put the aubergine bag into the bag is a detail.

Let's put these two bags in that one.

The reference of "these" and "that" is clarified by body language (pointing etc)

Let's combine/consolidate (the bags)

Not that you don't alter the size of the bags in this process, so you don't make a "big" bag.
Or a wordy, but natural spoken form, including context:

Let's put the bags with the parsley and the aubergines in the big one, it'll be easier to carry that way.

Don't worry about logic, think about communication. What is the important ideas that you want to communicate.  In this case it is the idea of "becoming one" and "make it easier".

Ok, so I won't worry about the logic any longer, then would the sentence number 5 "Let's put each one inside the other." be a natural English? Can I use it without sounding unnatural?

Doesn't sound natural to me. Other than what? "Let's put all the bags into this one."

"each one inside the other" sounds like nesting them."Let's put them all together inside one bag."

I still prefer mine, but I'd probably get what you were saying in context. Yours doesn't have the basic communication element of "becoming one", but is concerned with "putting X inside Y"

You can also say:

Let's put all the bags together inside one bag.

That solution assumes that some of the bags are smaller bags to begin with, or that they could be rolled up to reduce their size somewhat.

consolidate is the word for combining multiple things together. From Merriam-Webster

to join together into one whole : unite
consolidate several small school districts

So you can say that you're going to consolidate all the shopping bags.
Often this implies you're going to transfer the contents of one bag into another, not put one bag into another bag, but that's not precluded.

Suppose A, B, C, and D are small bags, and E is the largest bag (with groceries in it).
You can phrase it in the following ways:

"We put bags A, B, C, and D into the biggest bag, E."
"We placed all the smaller bags into the largest one, E."
"We put all the other bags into E to make carrying them easier."

*Why avoid "putting A into B, and then into C"?"
Since bags don’t have rigid structures like boxes, it’s more practical to describe the action as putting all smaller bags directly into the largest one.
How to naturally express combining bags or boxes:
For bags:

"We put the bags one inside the other to make a single big bag."
"We combined the bags to carry them as one."

Using verbs like "nest," or "combine" ensures clarity and avoids ambiguity. These terms naturally describe the process of arranging multiple items into one.

Doesn't stack imply one on top of the other?

@TimR The smaller boxes can be stacked inside the large box.

Like Russian Matryoshka dolls?
